# How to fix this PHP error Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting this error in my WordPress theme after installing a plugin. I was using **Amy Movies 3.5.2 theme** and the plugin is **Amy Movie Extends 3.5.4**. I don't know if that is causing the problem. It shows the error at line 145 which is

```
    $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
    $cinema_slug    = ($permalinks['cinema_slug']) ? $permalinks['cinema_slug'] : 'cinema'; //This Line
```

Here is my full PHP code:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_create_postype_movie')) {
    function amy_movie_create_postype_movie() {
        $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
        $movie_slug     = isset($permalinks['movie_slug']) ? $permalinks['movie_slug'] : 'movie';

        $movie_args     = array(
            'labels'            => array(
                'name'          => esc_html__('Movies', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'singular_name' => esc_html__('Movies', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'add_new_item'  => esc_html__('Add Movie', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'add_new'       => esc_html__('Add or Import Movie', 'amy-movie-extend'),
            ),
            'public'                => true,
            'has_archive'           => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-video-alt',
            'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'comments'),
            'rewrite'               => array(
                'slug'          => $movie_slug,
                'with_front'    => true,
                'feeds'         => true,
                'pages'         => true,
            ),
        );

        register_post_type('amy_movie', $movie_args);
    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_create_postype_movie');
}

// Genre
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_create_taxonomy_genre')) {
    function amy_movie_create_taxonomy_genre() {
        $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
        $genre_slug     = isset($permalinks['genre_slug']) ? $permalinks['genre_slug'] : 'genre';

        register_taxonomy('amy_genre',array('amy_movie', 'amy_tvshow'), array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => array(
                'name'              => esc_html__('Genres', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'singular_name'     => esc_html__('Genre', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'search_items'      => esc_html__('Search Genre', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'all_items'         => esc_html__('All Genres', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'parent_item'       => esc_html__('Parent Genre', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__('Parent Genre:', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'edit_item'         => esc_html__('Edit Genre', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'update_item'       => esc_html__('Update Genre', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'add_new_item'      => esc_html__('Add New Genre', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'new_item_name'     => esc_html__('New Genre Name', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'menu_name'         => esc_html__('Genres'),
            ),
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug'                  => $genre_slug,
                'with_front'            => true,
                'hierarchical'          => true,
            ),
        ));
    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_create_taxonomy_genre');
}

// Actor
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_create_taxonomy_actor')) {
    function amy_movie_create_taxonomy_actor() {
        $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
        $actor_slug     = isset($permalinks['actor_slug']) ? $permalinks['actor_slug'] : 'actor';

        register_taxonomy('amy_actor',array('amy_movie', 'amy_tvshow'), array(
            'hierarchical'      => false,
            'labels'            => array(
                'name'              => esc_html__('Actors', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'singular_name'     => esc_html__('Actor', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'search_items'      => esc_html__('Search Actor', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'all_items'         => esc_html__('All Actors', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'edit_item'         => esc_html__('Edit Actor', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'update_item'       => esc_html__('Update Actor', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'add_new_item'      => esc_html__('Add New Actor', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'new_item_name'     => esc_html__('New Actor Name', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'menu_name'         => esc_html__('Actors'),
            ),
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug'                  => $actor_slug,
                'with_front'            => true,
                'hierarchical'          => true,
            ),
        ));

    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_create_taxonomy_actor');
}

// Director
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_create_taxonomy_director')) {
    function amy_movie_create_taxonomy_director() {
        $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
        $director_slug  = isset($permalinks['director_slug']) ? $permalinks['director_slug'] : 'director';

        register_taxonomy('amy_director',array('amy_movie', 'amy_tvshow'), array(
            'hierarchical'      => false,
            'labels'            => array(
                'name'              => esc_html__('Directors', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'singular_name'     => esc_html__('Director', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'search_items'      => esc_html__('Search director', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'all_items'         => esc_html__('All Directors', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'edit_item'         => esc_html__('Edit Director', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'update_item'       => esc_html__('Update Director', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'add_new_item'      => esc_html__('Add New Director', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'new_item_name'     => esc_html__('New Director Name', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                'menu_name'         => esc_html__('Directors'),
            ),
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug'                  => $director_slug,
                'with_front'            => true,
                'hierarchical'          => true,
            ),
        ));

    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_create_taxonomy_director');
}

// Cinema
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_create_posttype_cinema')) {
    function amy_movie_create_posttype_cinema() {
        if ((amy_get_option('enable_m_cinema', true) == false) || (amy_get_option('enable_m_cinema', true) == true && amy_get_option('is_single_cinema', false) == true)) {
            return;
        }

/***********This Line***********/
/***********This Line***********/
/***********This Line***********/

        $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
        $cinema_slug    = ($permalinks['cinema_slug']) ? $permalinks['cinema_slug'] : 'cinema'; //Line 145 ERROR HERE

/***********This Line***********/
/***********This Line***********/
/***********This Line***********/




        register_post_type('amy_cinema',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name'          => esc_html__('Cinemas', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                    'singular_name' => esc_html__('Cinemas', 'amy-movie-extend'),
                ),

                'public'        => true,
                'has_archive'   => true,
                'menu-icon'     => 'dashicons-building',
                'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'comments'),
                'rewrite'       => array(
                    'slug'                  => $cinema_slug,
                    'with_front'            => true,
                    'hierarchical'          => true,
                ),
            )
        );
    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_create_posttype_cinema');
}

// Custom Fields
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_custom_fields_create_taxonomy')) {
    function amy_movie_custom_fields_create_taxonomy() {
        $custom_fields = amy_get_option('movie_custom_fields');

        if (!empty($custom_fields)) {
            foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
                if ($field['type'] == 'category' || $field['type'] == 'person') {
                    $name           = (isset($field['name']) && $field['name'] != '') ? $field['name'] : '';
                    $singular_name  = (isset($field['singular_name']) && $field['singular_name'] != '') ? sanitize_title($field['singular_name']) : sanitize_title($name);

                    register_taxonomy($singular_name,array('amy_movie', 'amy_tvshow'), array(
                        'hierarchical'      => false,
                        'labels'            => array(
                            'name'              => $name,
                        ),
                        'show_ui'           => true,
                        'show_admin_column' => true,
                        'query_var'         => true,
                        'rewrite'           => array(
                            'slug'                  => $singular_name,
                            'with_front'            => true,
                            'hierarchical'          => true,
                        ),
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_custom_fields_create_taxonomy');
}

if (!function_exists('amy_movie_create_post_type_tvshow')) {
    function amy_movie_create_post_type_tvshow() {
        if (amy_get_option('enable_m_cinema', true) == true) {
            return;
        }

        $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
        $tvshow_slug    = isset($permalinks['tvshow_slug']) ? $permalinks['tvshow_slug'] : 'tvshow';

        $args   = array(
            'labels'                => array(
                'name'                  => esc_html__('Tv Shows', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'singular_name'         => esc_html__('Tv Show', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'search_items'          => esc_html__('Search Tv Show', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'all_items'             => esc_html__('All Tv Shows', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'edit_item'             => esc_html__('Edit Tv Show', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'update_item'           => esc_html__('Update Tv Show', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'add_new_item'          => esc_html__('Add New Tv Show', 'amy-movie-helper'),
            ),
            'public'                => true,
            'has_archive'           => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'comments'),
            'rewrite'               => array(
                'slug'                  => $tvshow_slug,
                'with_front'            => true,
                'feeds'                 => true,
                'pages'                 => true
            )
        );

        register_post_type('amy_tvshow', $args);
    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_create_post_type_tvshow', 12);
}

// register chapper post type.
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_create_post_type_season')) {
    function amy_movie_create_post_type_season() {
        if (amy_get_option('enable_m_cinema', true) == true) {
            return;
        }

        $permalinks     = get_option('amy_movie_permalinks');
        $season_slug    = isset($permalinks['season_slug']) ? $permalinks['season_slug'] : 'season';

        $args   = array(
            'labels'                => array(
                'name'                  => esc_html__('Seasons', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'singular_name'         => esc_html__('Season', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'search_items'          => esc_html__('Search Season', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'all_items'             => esc_html__('All Seasons', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'edit_item'             => esc_html__('Edit Season', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'update_item'           => esc_html__('Update Season', 'amy-movie-helper'),
                'add_new_item'          => esc_html__('Add New Season', 'amy-movie-helper'),
            ),
            'public'                => true,
            'has_archive'           => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'supports'              => array('title', 'editor'),
            'rewrite'               => array(
                'slug'                  => $season_slug,
                'with_front'            => true,
                'feeds'                 => true,
                'pages'                 => true
            )
        );

        register_post_type('amy_season', $args);
    }

    add_action('init', 'amy_movie_create_post_type_season', 12);
}
```

Could anybody kindky say how to fix this error?

Comment: Apparently `$permalinks` is false, so you can't get the values from it

Comment: Can you say how to fix this? or what should i do now with this line? It'll be a great help i've been trying my whole day to fix this

Comment: Try `$cinema_slug = $permalinks['cinema_slug'] ?? 'cinema';`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `$permalinks` is false, so you'll need to make sure it's truthy in that line

```
$movie_slug     = $permalinks && isset($permalinks['movie_slug']) ? $permalinks['movie_slug'] : 'movie';
```